# Xcode 10.1 - How to fix broken copy/paste not working?

Tags: clipboard, xcode10, xcode10.1

I'm intermittently encountering a frustrating bug in Xcode where the copy <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does fails with the following symptoms:

- It clears existing item in the pasteboard
- It fails to copy content into pasteboard
- Upon pressing CMD+V a sound is playing and nothing gets pasted (no previous or current item)
- Both <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or Edit>Copy can fail the same way.

I've seen a number of suggestions to kill the Pasteboard process and restart Xcode, however this does not seem to work (well). The problem persists and is quite annoying and intermittent. I encountered it on multiple devices(Multiple iMacs, Macbook Air 2011, Macbook Air 2018) with multiple versions of OS (High Sierra/ Mojave).

**How do I permanently fix/restore Xcode 10 copy/paste functionality?**

It might be my superstition at this point, but it appears that if I hold the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> longer than usual by 0.3 seconds or so, it is more likely to actually work. If I press the buttons normally (rapidly), it gets stuck in the broken state with the existing pasteboard item gone(so something did register), but the item I wanted to copy not available.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Turning off the 'Automatically Sync Pasteboard' option in the Edit menu of the Simulator.

**Ref**: [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106140)